# Rewriterule shows wrong URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a webapplication working on:
next3.info:83
I want to go there with:
weburen.next3.nl so I used this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =weburen.next3.nl
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^83
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://next3.info:83/ [L]
```

It goes to:
next3.info:83 so the redirect works
But I want to see:
weburen.next3.nl not next3.info:83
How can I make this work?

Comment: did below answer help?

Answer (score 0):

When you use absolute URL for RewriteRule substitution, it will always force external redirect to new hostname. If you want to preserve original hostname, you have to configure as proxy by enabling `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` modules, then add [P] flag to your RewriteRule. As example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://next3.info:83/ [P]
```

[P] flag is documented in the link:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Comment: @berbast above answer help?